# jQuery, resize then fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I search around but don't know how to do this one... I receive through $.ajax() data then render through jQuery template. I want:

1. create template object (this one done)
2. set it hide() (this one done)
3. insert it to page with height 1 or 0
4. then make some effect that will re-size (by height) this inserted div
5. make fadeIn on this template

So base thing that i need to re-size (slowly) page, add there hidden div (rendered by template) and then make fadeIn function on it. The same thing on fadeOut.

Comment: Can you provide your code or a JSFiddle so we don't have to mock-up the entire example? :)

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you attempt to solve your problem and can post code that others can help you with.  Your question is just asking for the solution.  Give it a try and update your question with some code.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: stack is not the best place where should ask question at all! why? look how many minuses for what? it's simple question, on stack there are A LOT OF question from manuals and NO minuses, here some 'smart-guys' think that it's dummy question, try do it before you tick minus, and you know who sets minuses? people that has NO IDEA how to deal with a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use callback functions like this -

```
$( "#something" ).animate({
    height: "100",
    width : "100"
}, 5000, function() {
    $('#someOtherThing').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: yeah but start point can be different, for example one div is height: 200 and another width: 300, I need reversed 'blind' (http://jqueryui.com/effect/) effect 'from up to down' and only then call fadeIn. Reversed blind effect give me 're-size' of page, and fadeIn will show my div.